# Android onkeypress vs oninput in text input

Tags: javascript, android, forms, mobile

recently while building an autocomplete widget for a mobile site i'm working on i came across this bug. Android, tested on 2.3, handles the oninput event incorrectly. It seems to fire the event two times instead of just once. firefox on android seems to be doing the the thing.

i had to change to onkeypress to avoid the multiple events.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/ryanseddon/H5F/pull/4

seems that "onkeypress" performs better for these tasks

Comment: That is good for browsers that don't support the oninput event. But if it's supported but not implemented correctly, that's a little different.